# How can I replace certain characters within nodes/elements in a XML file?

Tags: xml, batch-file, replace, cmd

I am trying to automatically replace "illegal" characters from a XML file because of a sync with a SharePoint list, which doesn't allow these.

Example XML: books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella & Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls + Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I would like to replace the characters *, &, + and # from the author fields in this file with another character or word like "and".
So the replace actions must not be executed on the other fields like genre, price, etc.

The replace action must be called from a batch script in Windows so I'm able to let it automatically run every minute.

Can I script with within a simple Windows batch file? or are there any simple/freeware utilities which provides? I would rather not use powershell, vbscript and C# because the lack of support on the server.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's not well-formed (and it isn't, because of the bare `&` characters) then it's not XML - this needs to be fixed in the application that generates the catalog file to make it generate well-formed XML rather than text-with-some-angle-brackets-in-it.  You may be able to fix this particular problem post-hoc but there are many different kinds of errors that can cause this sort of data not to be well formed, some more subtle than others.  Tell your source that if they want to claim to produce XML then they should make sure that it really _is_ XML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q20399012.txt) DO (
 ECHO "%%a"|FINDSTR /r /i /b   ".*<author>.*</author>" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO(%%a
 ) ELSE (
  SET line=%%a
  SET line=!line:^&=and!
  SET line=!line:+=but!
  SET line=!line:#=qlj!
  SET "newline="
  CALL :substar
  ECHO(!line!
 )
 )
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF

:substar
SET c1=!line:~0,1!
SET line=!line:~1!
IF "!c1!"=="*" SET c1=xor
SET newline=!newline!!c1!
IF DEFINED line GOTO substar
SET "line=!newline!"
GOTO :eof
```

This isn't perfect - input file is `q20399012.txt` and outputs to `newfile.txt`

Unlikely to be harmful - but probably won't work properly on autor lines that contain `!` or `%`

Suggest you check results by executing

```
fc q20399012.txt newfile.txt
```

after each run to show the changes made.